# Use Visual Studio Code Remote - Containers in Visual Studio 2022

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-code, visual-studio-2022

I recently tested Visual Studio Code Remote - Containers extension that lets you use a Docker container as a full-featured development environment.

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/containers

It works really well and Microsoft uses it in their guide for

> Create and deploy a cloud-native ASP.NET Core microservice

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/training/modules/microservices-aspnet-core/2-deploy-application

This guide is in turn referenced from eShopOnContainers that is a sample .NET Core reference application, powered by Microsoft, based on a simplified microservices architecture and Docker containers.

https://github.com/dotnet-architecture/eShopOnContainers#are-you-new-to-microservices-and-cloud-native-development

Is it possible to use this feature in Visual Studio 2022?

I know `GitHub Codespaces` can be used as well for this.

https://github.com/features/codespaces

Answer (score 0):

If you use this function in visual studio, I hope this visual stduio Docker container tool documentation can help you:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/containers/?view=vs-2022

First create an ASP.NET Core web application and deploy the container to Azure. Specific steps can be viewed:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/containers/deploy-app-service?view=vs-2022

In the Azure portal, you can open your deployed App Service. You can view settings for your deployed App Service by opening the Container settings menu (when you are using Visual Studio 2019 version 16.4 or later).

You can view the container information, view or download logs, or set up continuous deployment.